# Deleting VBA code in the Personal Workbook (Excel for Mac) - can't unhide

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to create VBA code in Excel for Mac and save it in the Personal Macro Workbook. The VBA code does not work and I would like to delete it.

I went to **Developer -> Macros -> Delete** but I got the message "Cannot edit a macro on a hidden workbook - Unhide the workbook using the unhide command".
So I went to **Format -> Sheet** but the unhide command was not available.

Then I thought, maybe the worksheet is protected? I went to **Review -> Protection -> Workbook**, but I have no password to input... it says it is optional anyway. I unclick "Protect Structure" but now I can't click "OK" anymore so I am stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open list of macros (Alt+F8), select your macro, click "Step Into" and delete the code of your macro from `Sub nameOfYourMacro` to `End Sub`. If the window with question appear, click "OK". Save this window and close it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The only problem is that the shortcut seems to be taken now... it looks like I can't use the shortcut of the deleted macro for another macro.

Comment: You can try to restart Excel or record macro without shortcut and add it later in "Options..." on macro list.